# SQL SSIS 2012 Loop Counter by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, counter, foreach-loop-container

Hey guys I've got a table close to below and i need to add column3; counting +1 for each additional row that has the same value of the first column. Do i need a foreach loop? What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Thank!

```
column1 | column2 | column3
A1        123         1     
A1        168         2
A1        738         3
B1        122         1
B2        138         2
B3        945         3
B4        174         4
C1        948         1
C2        168         2
C3        849         3
```

Comment: Is the data stored in a table and you need to compute Column3 or do you need to compute Column3 as you're loading data into a table? It appears that your logic is: Generate a unique value, starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 for each value in Column1 ordered by Column2

Comment: The data would be coming from a record set. Im joining several tables before this point. I need to generate column3 values at this point, it does not exist in the recordset right now.

Comment: When you say recordset - have you stored this data into an SSIS Variable of type Object that you used as a Recodset Destination in a Data Flow Task? Or, are you simply referring to the data that's ready for import into SQL Server as your recordset?

Comment: Yes sir, I am storing it into an SSIS Variable of type Object and not for any specific reason -I'm just stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using the DENSE_RANK() function with SQL at OLE DB Connection.

```
Select column1
,column2
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by column1 Order By column2) "column3"
from my_table.
```